# How can I use ActiveRecord to compare columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my application, Users can join Houses.

In the `Houses` table is a `bedrooms` column of type integer.

Given

```
h = House.new
h.users
```

We can see all users that have joined a particular house.

Once `h.users == h.bedrooms`, I want to remove that house from the houses#index view.

The index action of the HousesController currently looks like this:

```
  def index
    @houses = House.all
  end
```

House.rb

```
has_many :bookings
has_many :users, through: :bookings
```

What should I set @houses to in order to achieve the result I desire?

Comment: what is the relation between mansion and house?

Comment: @mandeep - Whoops! That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Add Counter Cache for users count in House model

then in HousesController

```
def index
    @houses = House.where("users_count < ?",bedrooms)
  end
```

Comment: We're getting close, but I'm getting 'undefined method bedrooms for HousesController. Looking into how to add a counter cache.

Comment: Getting same error with counter cache. Added my House model to original question.

Comment: Now that you've added a counter cache, the houses table has users_count and bedrooms columns, so the query becomes, "users_count < bedrooms".

Comment: Upon further research, I've found that counter_cache doesn't work for many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the associations are defined, that is: is there a *1-to-1* relationship between users and bookings?

If that's the case, then this works:

```
class User
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :houses, through: :bookings
end

# column 'user_id', integer
# column 'house_id', integer
class Booking
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :house
end

# column 'bedrooms', integer
class House
  has_many :bookings
  has_many :users, through: :bookings


  def is_full?
    bedrooms <= bookings.count
  end
end
```